# Края объекта с тёмной линией, когда у камера проекция в Orthographic

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Как убрать тёмную линию на краю объекта, когда у камера проекция в Orthographic в Perspective не наблюдается данной проблемы

Я использую Unity 2019.1.10f1 (64-bit)

Orthographic: (Приглядитесь куда указывает стрелка)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Perspective:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В настройка тени от света, установить Bias на 0.5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]